# Работа WebSocket в Java (spring и android)

Tags: java, websocket

Никак не могу понять, как реализовывать сокеты на java на клиенте. Есть несколько проблем:

1) Если реализовывать клиентскую сторону с помощью библиотек типа *okhttp3*, то для отправки сообщения используется метод `send(String text)`. Почти все примеры клиентской части выполнены на js, где этот метод имеет 2 параметра (первый - путь вызываемого метода, второй - передаваемое сообщение).

Например, вот так выглядит реализация вызова для signalR в JS:

`this.hubConnection.invoke('SelectCurrentGroup', groupName)`

Вопрос: как в java задавать вызываемый клиентом метод? Все библиотеки для java выполнены в стиле как *okhttp3*?

2) Если в spring использовать `.withSockJS()`, то подключиться к сокетам через путь с ws:// становится невозможно.

Чтобы можно было подключаться обоими способами (с библиотеками поддержки STOMP и без них), правильно ли делать так, как указано ниже?

```
    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/api").setAllowedOrigins("*")
    registry.addEndpoint("/api").setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй эти нижеследующие библиотеки:

- com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid
- org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket

Comment: Первую библиотеку пробовал и она выдает ошибку (java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #2 bootstrap method) при запуске базового примера. Больше ничего не пишет.  
Вторая же так же предлагает один отправляемый параметр без указания пути. И, в любом случае, хотел бы узнать как правильно отправлять запрос, если в методе отправки всего один параметр.

Answer (score 0):

@Asenwer Qwerty А кто тебе мешает этот один параметр считать json ? и вот у тебя будет любое число параметров

Comment: Наличие STOMP мне мешает. Читай вопрос внимательнее

Comment: @Asenwer Qwerty если есть большая необходимость сделать что-то универсальное  - то, как вариант, первый параметр использовать как "заглушку"  , а во втором параметре передавать все и метод и данные (в json)